# hide unwanted element from list of elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of div just like this:

```
<div class="portfolio-categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat-all" class="active">ALL WORKS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat-1">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat-2">Commercial</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-container">
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-1">1</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-1">2</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-1">3</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-2">4</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-2">5</div>
</div>
```

There are 3 menus: ALL WORKS, Residential, Commercial. If I click Residential, all "portfolio-item" beside "portfolio-cat-1" will be hidden. The same goes for Commercial, all div "portfolio-item" beside "portfolio-cat-2" will be hidden.

I use .not() for this. Here is my jquery code:

```
$(".portfolio-categories a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id=$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];

    $(".portfolio-item").not(".portfolio-cat-"+id).fadeOut(400, function(){
        alert("done");
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I click Residential (cat-1) all portfolio-cat-1 div are hidden instead of portfolio-cat-2. What went wrong? Is it not .not() that I should use?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".portfolio-categories a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id=$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
    console.log(id)
    $(".portfolio-item:not(.portfolio-cat-"+id+")").fadeOut(400, function(){
        console.log("done");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio-categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat-all" class="active">ALL WORKS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat-1">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="cat-2">Commercial</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-container">
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-1">1</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-1">2</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-1">3</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-2">4</div>
    <div class="portfolio-item portfolio-cat-2">5</div>
</div>
```

Try using the selector `:not()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".portfolio-item").fadeIn(400).not(".portfolio-cat-"+id).fadeOut(400);
```

You need to bring back the previously hidden elements using fadeIn

Try the above line